# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Programming Puzzles & Code Golf's [second moderator election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Mego] [image: DJMcMayhem]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4557875250724864/0).

Comment: Congrats dudes!

Comment: right now, [only dj is mod](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10OAiJwG5GuUDjZ4i8B5wxytiTC1Cox9Dbyta6C7wkIM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @tfbninja: Blame caching. The one source of truth: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Will [Doorknob ♦](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) still be a moderator?

Comment: @MDXF Yes, Doorknob spends more time moderating than you can tell from his publicly visible activity.

Comment: Yeah, exactly my first two picks! Congratulations!

Answer (score 29):

Thanks for all of the support during the election! I am proud to be a moderator of this fine site!

Comment: who downvotes that...

Comment: @tfbninja Either someone who didn't vote for Mego... or Geobits.

Comment: There must be two geobits now

Comment: @tfbninja Blame caching. 3+ at time of reading.