# Farewell, for now

Tags: discussion, moderators

With my dwindling activity over the last few months, this probably doesn't come as a surprise... but I've decided to hand in my diamond. My reasons are similar to [Alex's, half a year ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14876/8478), in that there are various things (none bad, thankfully) these days that take up my time otherwise, and recently I just haven't had much motivation for code golf (and by extension, moderating this community).

The other, fantastic mods have been doing a great job of handling the workload despite my recent absence, and so I don't think there will be an election immediately.

This is hopefully not goodbye forever. While I'm not spending my time on recreational programming right now, I don't think I've written my last esolang, and when I get back into it, I'm sure I'll be golfing here again as well. Until then, I'll be lurking in the PPCG-Gaming chatroom for the foreseeable future and I'm always happy to help with any questions about my esolangs (just ask one of the mods to superping me if necessary), and to hand out any of my indefinite bounties should someone claim them.

Thanks to everyone who made this community a joy to spend time in and for putting your trust in me to moderate it over the last years, and I hope to see your somewhere down the road!

Comment: Nooo! You were the chosen one. Hate to see you go, but of course, life happens. Good luck with whatever you do!

Comment: Does that mean we need to elect a replacement? Who could possibly replace our most decorated user of all time‽

Comment: Good luck with the future and whatever other things you decide to do. It's been great with you as part of our community. Thanks for everything!

Comment: And I was under the impression you had more time, now that you just finished Tametsi. :)

Comment: @Adám He explicitly noted that he doesn't think there needs to be an election to replace him immediately.

Comment: You know we will miss you. I never told you, but your answers were one of my motivations to join this site.

Comment: Thanks for all the kind words, everyone! :)

Answer (score 27):

### Thanks for being part of PPCG (and hopefully, its future)

Good luck with whatever the future holds for you, and thanks for moderating and participating in this community! Hoping to see you back as soon as possible, recalling the [good](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87482/hexaregex-a-tribute-to-martin-ender) ol' [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55574/dennis-doorknob-martin-b%C3%BCttner-chris-jester-young-pizzeria) dedicated to / inspired by you, and of course your [*literally* beautiful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art/35601#35601) submissions :-)

Comment: Much as I like that Tweetable Mathematical Art image, my favourites of Martin's are the later ones, his most recent one being my favourite of anyone's on that challenge (the Buddhabrot). Here they are newest first: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=inquestion%3a35569%20user%3a8478

Answer (score 13):

Of all the wonderfully welcoming people here, you have made me feel the most welcome.

It's been great discussing things with you over the years, learning from you, and watching discussions with others that I couldn't keep up with but enjoyed nonetheless. Although when explaining direct to me you have a knack for judging just the right level that I can grasp it.

I remember you being part of the team helping me group golf one of my early answers down enough to be valid to post - that really got across to me how inclusive and supportive this community is.

You talked me into being a mod over on CG.SE when I had very little confidence (which has improved a lot as a result...), and patiently answered my questions beforehand, and then during too, and wrote me a beautiful nomination post which I endeavour to live up to.

The community is what makes this site, and you've been a huge part of guiding and supporting us all, quite aside from the technical contributions like a [variety of twisted esolangs](https://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Martin_Ender) and the [leaderboard to make golf more per-language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet). Looking forward to your return, and hoping you thoroughly enjoy all the things you're doing in between.

Comment: Aww, stop cutting onions. :)

Answer (score 9):

You were really good handling the diamond you were given by us, the community. Personally, you helped me get accustomed to this site and its norms very much, alongside the other then-moderators, a menace, a magpie and a doorknob.

Your esoteric programming languages have always been challenging me, and you literally surprised everybody with some of your submissions. You especially handled CJam like a real expert, and nothing stopped you from going extreme from time to time.

I remember [the time you got married](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29985639#29985639), as well as [the time you stepped down from Computer Graphics Stack Exchange](https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/187/8992). Those must have been life-changing events. I hope this will be yet another event, and that your new life will be much more performing and better, and that your career will go on to be grand and fruitful.

Of course, you stepping down from the moderator position isn't really a happy event for us, but, according to the reasons you've provided, I'd say it was the right decision. We've now got a refreshed team with a cat DJ and a penguin, as well as the same menace and doorknob we've had for a much longer time, so it will hopefully not be a great loss for the community. And, we can always open up a new election if necessary. ;-)

Enjoy the rest of your life, and, if you ever come back, you'll be more than welcome. :-)

Farewell.

Answer (score 5):

## Don't be a stranger

Back when I would just lurk in TNB, without any challenges or answers posted, interacting with folks like you greatly influenced my decision to join the community. You're a good guy so to restate the title of this answer, don't be a stranger. After all, we've been with you through life events like the changing of your last name which was stressful for everyone ;)