# So what happens now?

Tags: discussion, policy, moderators, election

[Martin Ender is stepping down as moderator.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16843/43319)

We had [a moderator election](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/2) only about half a year ago. There were three candidates, of which two were elected. The last candidate was [PhiNotPi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-154976).

Do we have to go through all the hassle of another election process or can we just offer the position to PhiNoPi.

I think it is highly unlikely that anybody else stands a chance in a full election.

Comment: To cite the linked post, *The other, fantastic mods have been doing a great job of handling the workload despite my recent absence, and so **I don't think there will be an election immediately.***

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Hm, clearly I was so emotionally affected by this that I lost the ability to read.

Answer (score 11):

I think PhiNotPi would make a fantastic mod, but we're a graduated site now so if at some point there arises a need for an extra moderator, I'd be very surprised if that didn't involve an official election.

Answer (score 4):

> So what happens now?

Nothing. Only time will tell if Martin's resignation has really caused problems with the diamond moderators, and, if so, a new moderator can get appointed or elected.