# I'm stepping down

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's been an honor to serve as your moderator for the past four years. I would like to continue to do so, but after witnessing how Stack Exchange treats their volunteers, I decided that I'm no longer going to volunteer for them.

The affected former sextuple moderator, Monica Cellio, [has summarized what happened to her](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193/19824).

I'd like to make clear that my decision to resign was based solely on the above, not on the proposed changes to the code of conduct. If I guessed them correctly, I agree with the intentions behind the future changes. Time will tell if I agree with the actual changes, which are not yet known to me.

Comment: I admire your strength in taking this step. Thanks for everything you've contributed.

Comment: Thank you for all you have done for the network, and for standing up for your principles.

Comment: It's sad that this happened, but I hope you will stay around.

Comment: Great moral fiber. You'll be missed!

Comment: You will be missed! Thank you for all you have done for PPCG and taking a stand for your own beliefs!

Comment: [**Meta post showing all the resignations across the network**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

Comment: [Meta Codegolf: Should we move?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18136/should-we-consider-planning-a-move-off-stackexchange)

Answer (score 101):

> **UPDATE (since 2019-10-30)**: So, it looks like [a test is currently being ran](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337228/225091). I'm not sure if it will have good results, but it surely looks like a big step towards the goal that finally needs to be achieved. There's also a discussion currently progressing in the comments of that answer. Yes, this doesn't solve all of the current issues (e.g. the "retroactive" relicensing), and it doesn't even solve the specific issue that caused the main uproar (Monica's demotion), but it *might* solve what caused the latter issue in the first place. Of course, [Monica still deserves justice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/225091), even if she will eventually end up remaining *justly* demoted, and, personally, I'm not contributing until it gets sorted out, but, since late October, I'm starting to see some light at the end of the tunnel. I hope that everything gets resolved timely.
>
> **UPDATE (since 2019-10-23)**: So, there's another post, or, shall I say, pair of posts about the singular third-gender pronoun issue. It looks like the implementation of the new ruling is ever-so-slightly lighter than what the older post about it said. What I don't agree with this time around is that:
>
> 1. Nothing has actually *happened* about this yet, **there's been no adequate communication with Monica**. Remember that **the new CoC wasn't in place when she was expelled from the mod position.**
> 2. Said older post has been deleted, just like **it never happened in the first place**, with only vague references such as ["We tried to anticipate likely questions, but… missed the mark a bit."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/225091) still around.
>
> So, regarding my previous update, it looks like the problem I'm referring to has been partly fixed for now, but, since September 29th, no substantial action has been taken, and mere words for the public are simply nothing without that. To prove my point, see the [second apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/225091) and note that it once had a score of over +600. People started downvoting it after [the first announcement about the CoC changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/225091) (now deleted) was posted (its net score was below -1600), and it now has a negative score as well. This signifies that, while the community supported the apology for a while, when the listed actions started taking place, the end result was not satisfactory at all, and therefore not in line with the most probable expectations it gave. There's currently nothing that prevents something similar from happening regarding the two new posts.
>
> **UPDATE (since 2019-10-10)**: I've seen the new CoC... I can say I'm not satisfied at all. The terms are just too strict IMHO, I'm 100% sure that people can perfectly come to terms with more lenient ones. If by 2019-11-01 this is not fixed, then I'll really stop contributing to Stack Exchange (I've already paused my activity).
>
> If the community moves elsewhere, I'll happily keep contributing. I love the community a lot, what I hate is Stack Exchange's recent decisions and possible abuse of power. I also have nothing against the CMs and most of the people who work at SE, I know not everyone over there is responsible.

## I fully support your decision to resign.

I've been reflecting on whether I'll continue participating in Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow in general since yesterday, when Monica was stripped of her diamonds for, um, *disagreeing civilly*. Not to mention the possibly illegal recent "retroactive" license change.

Nope. My life is more than SE, I won't let an internet website treat me unfairly, which I'm sure it'll do if no action is taken against this. The new CEO has until November 1st to bring justice back, otherwise probably bye bye for good.

Comment: I'm gonna be joining you. In the past couple weeks, there's been a pile-up of problems, and no one from the company has responded to any of it. There's nothing left here if this continues. A month is a long time - we'll see I guess

Comment: @Zoe Eh, I've been participating in SE since 2013, so this is not so easy a decision to make, and it also accounts for the change of hands that will happen on October 1. However, I can't let something non-vital called "Stack Exchange" drain me, especially since I have more important things to do and a whole life ahead of me. I've chosen a month because I know the mess won't get fixed in one week, for example, and I've had many experiences overall, so I would hate to leave just for the mess to be proven temporary.

Comment: The whole arbitration thing has really got me concerned for the organization. I love participating here and I love the idea of SE. I have seen nothing from them to convince me that their latests maneuvers are in the best interests of the company or of this site's users. Not even a statement to that effect. Very worrying. I have a bad feeling that one day I'm going to try and login to this site, and find myself facing a 404 error after it's been shut down due to a legal dispute that they have no hope of winning or even properly defending themselves against. That will really suck.

Comment: I'm really attached to this site in my year here, but I also will leave if things aren't sorted out by November 1st.

Comment: I will also stop contributing at all if nothing has been fixed by November 1st.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the reference to Nov 1st when I read this post originally.

Comment: @mbomb007 There's no special reference, it's simply a month after October 1st, the day the new CEO was appointed. Even though I've seen the first step done (too late IMHO), I'm not really in for such things yet.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer November 1st was a codegolf.SE meme https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5834/34718 (now deleted)

Comment: @mbomb007 I know; I currently don't feel like doing memes.

Comment: I'll be quite sad to see you go, Erik. :( If you don't stay, I wish you to find or create an alternative community for coding puzzles.

Comment: @Cœur I don't think there's any other community out there where you can provide feedback to other peoples' solutions or to challenges directly (or even edit challenges). However, there's no way to participate here without participating in SE, as Axtell is currently abandoned. Also, I don't currently have any funds to create a website (even a 1¢/mo deal is too much). Alas, the things SE has lately done outweigh any deprivation I might feel from leaving it.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer you can also consider using crowdfunding to create a community.

Comment: @Adám Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 41):

If I hadn't [resigned](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14876/20469) a year and a half ago, I'd be doing it now.

In my time as a moderator you were an inspiration to me, Dennis. I'm sure your decision was not made lightly, and I think what you've chosen further underscores what we all already knew about you: your commitment to fostering a good community.