# January 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

This community last had an election last year, and has recently seen their moderator team reduced by two.

As such, by request of the remaining two moderators on the team, and to find replacements for Mego and Dennis, we're looking at scheduling an election to start somewhere in January 2020. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in January '20.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Comment: That largely depends on whether you've resolved the situation with Monica or not, and given you've started [censoring links to the gofundme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/381197), the magic 8 ball says... "Very Doubtful"

Comment: Dennis and Mego stepped down for a reason. Judging for the vote counts in [their](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/im-stepping-down) [annoucements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18240/its-time-for-me-to-leave), many people agree with their motives and respect their decision. Running for moderator now would feel, to a large extent, like going against that cause

Comment: Given that many people, in addition to Mego and Dennis, have stated that they would stop or greatly decrease their participation to Code Golf, I doubt we even need new mods given the current activity.

Comment: If you're going to check our pulse, you're going to find the community alive and incredibly angry at the SE administration. Your recalculation of reputation will not appease us.

Comment: Note that DJMcMayhem, in their post stepping down as moderator indicated that they wanted the community to find a replacement moderator: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18476/20080

Comment: [_A site could be shut down if there are not enough people to moderate it_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342915/is-there-a-mechanism-for-closing-launched-se-sites/342916#342916). This makes me qualify my comment above. If we reach a point where the site's continuity is at stake I'm sure people will want to run as moderators to keep this community going

Answer (score 26):

(Ignoring badge requirements)

I would run. I fundamentally disagree with many of Stack Exchange's policies. And, should I run and on the off-chance, actually get elected, I would not endorse all of SE's individual decisions, but I still have faith in the community, and if the community needs moderators, and especially since doubling the load on the other two moderators is understandably hard, I'm willing to help, for the community.

I still do not agree with how SE handled this, and I never will. A true apology or a peaceful resolution is well overdue and not sufficient, at this point. But, and maybe I'm too optimistic/loyal or have too much faith, I still believe the merit of this platform comes from the community. If an election were held sooner than now, or now, I wouldn't run, because after the whole community was damaged by these events and we lost two amazing moderators, it would feel like a hurried attempt to silence and patch over the problem, but January 2020 will be enough time to make a decision. I probably would run, but of course that's under the condition that nothing even worse happens.

But please, do not call it "replacing". Nobody can replace the hole left by Mego and Dennis, certainly not me. Their presence and support for our community will forever be missed, and I can only hope to start a time that grows to as great as their legacy, but never to replace it.

Comment: This is the only reason, in my opinion, for why we need an election however, it does seems like the community has also lessened, which compensates for the lack of moderators. I wouldn't know, a current moderator could probably answer this better but I think the question that needs asking is `Do we need more moderators?` rather than `Are people willing to be moderators?`.

Comment: @totallyhuman Well I specifically requested JNat to post this because I feel like we do.

Comment: I'm curious. What's your stance now, after the firing of community managers (Shog9 and Robert Cartaino)? Does that count as something "even worse"?

Comment: @StewieGriffin I've seen the two Goodbye posts for them, but I'm not exactly sure what happened and where to find that information. Could you send me a link or a quick rundown of what happened? It sounds like it might count as that, unfortunately...

Answer (score 14):

I would run. However, if I am elected, I'll step down. I don't think it is right to replace Mego and Dennis, who are clearly better candidates than me.

Comment: You aren't eligible to run without the required badges (Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms I'm aware but I'm trying to make a statement not actually become a moderator.

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms as far as I know, that's only the case on Stack Overflow

Comment: RedwolfPrograms, Doorknob, further, it seems only 300 rep is needed for a self-nomination: ["In the nomination phase, any community member in good standing with at least 300 reputation may nominate themselves — and only themselves — as a candidate in the moderator election."](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/02/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/)

Comment: So if you're not actually interested in the position, what's the point of this answer?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Sounds like [abstentionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstentionism).

Comment: @gerrit correct.