# Hanging up my diamond

Tags: discussion, moderation

Well. I never thought I'd be writing this message. I've logged into this site nearly every day for over 5 years. I truly love this community. I've learned so many things from it, and I have made countless friends that I consider just as close as people I know in real life. Which is why it's really hard to say that I'm going to be making an effort to start distancing myself from this site and the network.

I still reflexively open up The Nineteenth Byte every time I look at my phone, so I don't know how successful I will be at leaving. But I think it would be dishonest for me to continue to have a diamond next to my name. This is for a huge variety of reasons.

- I'm no longer a contributor. I still browse the site frequently, but I simply don't post on the site like I used to.
- I'm no longer moderating, or handling flags. A large contributor to that is because I feel like the majority of flags I see are requests to delete several year old posts that "technically" violate some overly specific combination of rules on meta penned over the last 8 years. But the other reason is burnout and a waning interest in the janitorial tasks on the site.
- I'm unhappy with the direction that SE is going. I don't feel a need to dwell too long on this one because it has been hashed and rehashed countless times across meta and chat. But I'm not willing to continue volunteering my time to a company that slanders it's volunteers then fires the employees that are interested in community building.
- I'd rather invest in more sustainable outlets for the community that aren't as reliant on an external company. I've been spending a lot of time on [The CGCC Discord Server](https://discord.gg/WCxqfcR), which I enjoy a lot. There is also a sister server I've been running for [talking about and playing games together.](https://discord.gg/6BU54qm)

I don't want to be hard to reach, since I greatly enjoy talking with everyone I've met from this site. You can email me at `DJMcMayhem[at]gmail[dot]com`, or add me on discord at `DJMcMayhem#9259`. I hope that the community finds a replacement for me quickly and isn't too negatively affected by having only one mod for a period of time.

Comment: You have been an outstanding member of this community and an excellent moderator. It's sad to see you step down but I completely understand why. See you around!

Comment: So long, @DJMcMayhem. I know I'll miss seeing you around these parts!

Comment: Two days isn't nearly long enough for this to be [tag:featured]. I hope the CM's don't routinely check "lesser" sites like this.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Good thing is, it's speculated that the 24-hr limitation is only regularly enforced on Meta Stack Overflow and not other sites (it's manually applied).

Comment: "A large contributor to that is because I feel like the majority of flags I see are requests to delete several year old posts that "technically" violate some overly specific combination of rules on meta penned over the last 8 years". This is probably my fault, although I wouldn't have thought that 130 flags over the course of five months was significant.

Comment: We wish you the best!